# Thymeleaf not able to find template in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to do a very simple thing, when an API "localhost:8080/my-project/success" is called, it should return an html template that is in "resources/templates" folder in my Spring Boot Project. But it gives me this error:

[image]

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/success", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String callback() {
        return "success_message";
    }
}
```

**HTML template location:**

[image: HTML Template Location]

**HTML Template Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" th:href="@{favicon.ico}"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f8f9fa">
<p style="
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 3%;
        font-size: larger;
        color: #009358;
        font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,Roboto,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Arial,&quot;Noto Sans&quot;,sans-serif,&quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;,&quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;,&quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;,&quot;Noto Color Emoji&quot;;
    ">
    Success MF
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried every other solution on SO related to this. Most of them can be categorized in below 2 categories:

1. Created a separated Config class for thymeleaf ((set classpath to 'classpath:/templates/', set suffix as HTML etc).
2. Added config for thymeleaf in application.properties instead (set classpath to 'classpath:/templates/', set suffix as HTML same thing as point 1).

Nothing has worked, I doubt if above config would be required in a spring boot project at all because all of this is auto-configured as soon as we import spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency.

A lot of other issues on SO are related to naming, missing a slash, not keeping template in /resources/templates. But I think I got that part right.

There are other projects where I have used thymeleaf for same (literally same use case) purpose. It works fine in them. I created a new Spring Boot project to test and it works in that too.

If needed, these are all 3 of the config files used:

**First Config**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Config1 implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final SomeInterceptor someInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(someInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/**/path-not-related-to-success-api/**");
    }
}
```

**Second Config**

```
@Configuration
public class Config2 {

    @Value("${connectionTimeOut}")
    private int connectionTimeOut;

    @Value("${readTimeOut}")
    private int readTimeOut;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();

        return restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(connectionTimeOut))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(readTimeOut))
                .additionalCustomizers(
                        new RestTemplateStandardCookieCustomizer()
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Third Config (not a config exactly, but it is used in second config file)**

```
public class RestTemplateStandardCookieCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
                .build();

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient)
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit 1: Adding stacktrace: **

```
  [ERROR],  18:20:14, [myProject], ERROR, org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "success_message": Error resolving template [success_message], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
  org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [success_message], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
      at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
  [ERROR],  18:20:14, [myProject], ERROR, org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/my-project].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/my-project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [success_message], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
  org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [success_message], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
      at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Comment: Remove all the custom (Thymeleaf) related config you tried. Check your configs for `@EnableWebMvc`, if found remove it. If not, there is something else going on, which isn't visible from what you posted here.

Comment: @M.Deinum Removed all custom config related to thymeleaf already. Nothing related to EnableWebMvc either. 

I have one EnableScheduling annotation on my main class though. But that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Add the error from the log (the fact that you get this error message also tells that there is a stracktrace and more detailed error in the logs) which will tell you exactly what is going on.

Comment: @M.Deinum Added stacktrace

Comment: @M.Deinum As from the logs I can see that thymeleaf is referring to spring 5 - "org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.....". But my spring version is <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Your controller only has `/success` in the `@GetMapping`. Do you configure `my-project` part of the URL you want to use somewhere else?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe yes in properties file server.servlet.context-path= /my-project

Comment: Is `2.1.6.RELEASE` the Spring version or the Spring Boot version?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Sprint boot   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question originally. Could not solve above issue. But as a work around, I did following:

1. removed thymeleaf dependency
2. Changed the controller to something like this:

   ```
   @Controller
   public class MessageController {
       @GetMapping(value = "/success", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
       @ResponseBody
       public String callback() {
           return "<html>...</html";
       }
   }
   ```

In the above code, I changed 2 things - added @ResponseBody and instead of giving the HTML template name as return value, pasted the whole HTML as a text. Not a very ideal way to do, but as my template is small and fixed, it seems alright.

Also, I removed thymeleaf related tags from HTML, like xmlns and th tags.

There was no need for success_message.html in templates folder so that can be deleted.